# how to create automatic number based on string, date in vb6

Tags: vb6

i try to make auto number based on format string, date and counter like USR20180815001, USR20180815002, when the day/date change it reset the counter to USR20180806001, USR20180806001, and so on. here is my code so far....

```
Sub AutomaticNumber()
    Call Connection
    Set Rs_User = New ADODB.Recordset
    Rs_User.Open "SELECT * FROM TBL_USER WHERE id_user IN (SELECT 
    MAX(id_user)FROM TBL_USER)ORDER BY id_user DESC", Conn
    Rs_User.Requery

    Dim x As String * 15
    Dim count As Long

    With Rs_User
        If .EOF Then
            x = "USR" + Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") + "001"
            NewNumber = x
        Else
            If Left(!id_user, 8) <> Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") Then
               x = "USR" + Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") + "001"
            Else
               Count = Right(!id_user, 3) + 1
               x = "USR" + Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") + Right("00" & 
               Count, 2)
            End If
        End If
      NewNumber = x
   End With
End Sub
```

this code can result USR20180805001, but when i try to add another record to databases, it can not add since the code failed to counter/increase the last 3 digit on the right. hence show error duplicate entry. thank you for the attention.

Comment: If you are storing `id_user` as `USR20180805001`, wouldn't `Left(!id_user, 8)` be `USR20180` rather than your expected `20180805`?

Comment: There's another error also: `... + Right("00" & Count, 2)` returns "##" not "###"